# Different view arrangement when it's centered in relative layout and overlapped

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-actionbar, android-view

I'm making custom view for an Action Bar. There have to be centered title, some action buttons at the right and navigation drawer button/back with title at the left.

I use RelativeLayout to place all elements, like so (this is demonstrating variant of real layout):

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionBarHomeContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:clickable="true">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/actionBarHomeImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/actionBarHomeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actionBarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionBarOptionsContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <!--Action items will be added here pragmatically-->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Custom action bar problem]

In most screen cases it's all OK (*green picture*), but when I deal with tight screens, my title is overlapping by home label (*yellow picture*). Keep in mind the this is only demonstrating situation, real items smaller than drew ones and case like this is rare. So my aim is in case of title is overlapped just place it in center of remain space between `actionBarHomeContainer` and `actionBarOptionsContainer` (*blue picture*). Is it possible somehow and what other solutions you may suggest to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing those chile `LinearLayout` with `Relative` and make use of `android:layout_toRightOf` or `android:layout_toleftOf' attributes on either Image or TextView.

Comment: If nothing is workout you need to change the root layout from Relative layout to Linear Layout. And use weigth property in your child views.That will helps to solve this problem.

Comment: Linear layout may solve problem with overlapping but it will get me not absolute centered title.

Answer (score 0):

There's an official and very easy solution to your problem: [**Don't mimic UI elements from other platforms**](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

> **Don't use labeled back buttons on action bars**
>
> Other platforms use an explicit back button with label to allow the user to navigate up the application's hierarchy. Instead, Android uses the main action bar's app icon for hierarchical navigation and the navigation bar's back button for temporal navigation. For more information, please review the [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) pattern.
>
> Follow this guideline to provide a consistent navigation experience across the platform.
>
> [image: Android action bar with up caret vs. iOS labeled "Back" button.]
>
> *Android action bar with up caret vs. iOS labeled "Back" button.*

Comment: Yeah, guidelines is pretty nice thing but it doesn't work in case I need in custom view like iOs anyway... So this is not a solution.

Comment: It is ***a*** solution. Mimicking UI elements from other platforms is the other solution, but it's bad practice. Especially if you know that it requires more effort from you, you're better off showing the client the Pure Android document and explaining: "You really don't want to aggravate your users."

Comment: I mostly agree with you, but there are circumstances I can't change. My question is about how to solve this layout problem, not about how to change my global approach. Anyway, you gave a nice point, thank you.